# Store texts in char array then compare the contents of array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out how I can store to the char array the user input. For example user input: hello, then char array[0] = "hello"; then when he input again "hello" it will not insert to the char array since it's already on the array.

```
Input: hello

Output: char array[] = {"hello"};

Input: world

Output:

char array[] = {"hello","world"};

Input: hello

checks: array[i] == "hello"

Output: don't insert to char array
```

I need a sample program please

Comment: make use of a function call each time you insert

Comment: Hi @Grace and welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you please share some code which you've tried and failed? This will help us understand and help you more precisely.

Comment: "user input: hello" with `char array[] = {"hello"};` following by `int i = 0;` then `array[i]` is a `char` that is `'h'`. Further, you compare strings with `strcmp` not `==`.

Comment: I can't seem to program it since I've got a lot or error, first by defining the size of the array since it only based on the input of the user, so everytime a user input, it can insert and insert to the array unless what she's inserting is already exists

Comment: Unless you are asked not to use std library, I don't see why you should not use a vector of strings. `std::vector<std::string>`. This will make it much easier for you.

Comment: I also get error on strcmp because of char issues. Please help to give me sample program.

Comment: You can store a single string is array of `char` not a list of `string`.

Comment: With `if (strcmp (array, "hello") == 0) puts ("equal"); else puts ("not equal");`?

Comment: can I ask for a sample program?

Comment: `std::set<std::string_view>`?

Comment: Well, you first have to pick C or C++. While you can use `cstring` function in C++, you generally think of using the `string` library which allows comparison by `==` in C++ instead of fundamental `char []` and `strcmp` from C which does not allow string comparison by `==`. You tagged the question C++, but everything you show is C. Which do you want?

Comment: @GraceJacinto _"can I ask for a sample program?"_ No, that's not what we're doing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might go with more C++-way using standard containers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string buffer;
    std::set<std::string> data;

    std::cin >> buffer;
    while (buffer != "quit")
    {
        if (data.find(buffer) == data.end())
        {
            auto res = data.insert(buffer);
            if (! res.second)
                std::cerr << "ERROR:: Could not insert string '" << buffer << "'." << std::endl;
        }
        else
            std::cout << "WARNING:: String '" << buffer << "' already found." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> buffer;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, you should do it in C-style of thinking:

- store string into buffer
- allocate new `char` array and put it into a list of arrays
- traverse through the list to find if a string is already there using `strcmp()` function
- don't forget to clean up any dynamically allocated memory at the end of your program - this would cause memory leaks

Answer (score 1):

The sample code using c++ would be like this, because this is C++ not only C we can use the features C++ provide as `std::string`, `std::vector` and many other useful algorithms like `std::find` implemented in STL. Hope this is what you want.

```
#include <string> // for std::string
#include <vector> // for std::vector
#include <iostream> // for std::cout, std::cin, and std::endl;
#include <algorithm> // for std::find

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> array;

    std::string line;
    std::cout << "Input : ";

    while(std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
        if (std::find(array.begin(), array.end(), line) == array.end()) { // If we can't find the string in the array
            array.push_back(line);
            std::cout << "{ ";
            for (std::string str: array) {
                std::cout << str << ", ";
            }
            std::cout << "}" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Output : Don't Insert" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```